# Cargar fuente en un archivo .ttf desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy tratando de agregar una fuente a mi proyecto, el tema es que necesito hacerlo todo desde JS, ¿Como cargo una fuente desde un archivo .ttf? ya que para aplicar la font-family necesito que la fuente este ya cargada (puesto que por lo visto solo recibe como parámetro el nombre de la fuente, no así su dirección absoluta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Nota:** En todos los `snippets` se carga una fuente `Web Open Font Format 2` (`.woff2`), porque no pude encontrar una `True Type` (`.ttf`). De todas formas las soluciones aplican de igual forma para fuentes `True Type`.

Se me ocurren 3 formas de cargar dinámicamente una fuente usando `javascript`:

1. Creando un tag `link` e indicando el `href` al archivo donde esta declarada la fuente.

```js
function loadFont() {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  document.head.appendChild(link);
}

//
document.getElementById('cargar').addEventListener('click', loadFont);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', arial;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola Mundo!<h1>
<button id="cargar">Cargar fuente</button>
```

2. Creando un tag `style` y utilizar [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@import) para cargar la fuente.

```js
function loadFont() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerText = "@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline');";
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}

//
document.getElementById('cargar').addEventListener('click', loadFont);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', arial;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola Mundo!<h1>
<button id="cargar">Cargar fuente</button>
```

3. Creando un tag `style` y declarando la ['font-face'](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

```js
function loadFont() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerText = "@font-face {\
    font-family: 'Bungee Inline';\
    src: local('Bungee Inline'), local('BungeeInline-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/bungeeinline/v2/Tb-1914q4rFpjT-F66PLCTxObtw73-qQgbr7Be51v5c.woff2) format('woff2');\
  }";
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}

//
document.getElementById('cargar').addEventListener('click', loadFont);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', arial;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola Mundo!<h1>
<button id="cargar">Cargar fuente</button>
```